# Code to Hide Only List Items with IDs

Tags: jquery, html, css, list, responsive-design

This might seem like a bit of a stretch, but I could really use some help with this.

I have this code:

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul class='top-nav'>
 <li id='pg911555508204622392'><a href="/" data-membership-required="0" >Home</a></li>
 <li id="active"><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
 <li id='pg198396790797236835'><a href="/contact.html" data-membership-required="0" >Contact</a></li>
 <li class="signup"><a href="/signup.html" data-membership-required="0" >Signup</a></li>
 </ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

I need a code (maybe jquery) that I can use so that when a screen is resized to 760px, every list item with an ID is hidden and leaves behind only the list items with CLASS. Normally, it would be easier to just hide the IDs in the css using "media queries" but since the pages (lis) will be created by different users and page IDs assigned at a random basis, I can't assume which to hide.

I just want to hide any list item that has an ID assigned to it and show any list item with CLASS. I'm guessing this can be done with jquery?

Here's a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Delinx/73kq3cup/

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`attribute selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select all `li` elements with `ID`s or `CLASS`es in `jQuery`:

```
$('li[id]').hide();
$('li[class]').show()
```

... or in CSS

```
li[class] {
    display: block;
}

li[id] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: N!c3 - for clarity: ".top-nav > [id] {display:none}" would be the appropriate CSS for /just/ the children of the top-nav classed DOM element(s).

Comment: That is correct, but the question is: "I just want to hide **any list item** that has an ID assigned to it and show any list item with CLASS"

Comment: Thanks everyone, it's all very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  var win = $(this); //this = window
  if (win.height() == 760) { 
      $('#navigation li[id]').hide(); 
      $('#navigation li[class]').show(); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($(this).width() < 760) {
        $('li[id]').hide();
    } else {
        $('li:hidden').show();
    }
}).resize();
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73kq3cup/5/)

---

There are some attribute selectors available in the jQuery, so in your case you just want to hide those `<li>` elements which has the `id` attribute, so you should be doing this `$('li[id]')` and its read only.

Answer (score 0):

**css only solution**

```
CSS [attribute~=value] Selector
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/t9qp3de5/)

html

```
<div id="1111">id only</div>
<div class="sdfsdfs">class only</div>
<div id="rrrrr1">id only</div>
<div class="sdfsdfs">class only</div>
<div id="sfvsv" class="sdfsdfs">class and id</div>
```

css

```
@media (max-width: 760px) {
    div[id] {
        display:none;
    }
}
```